# How to update the hostname of the master node in an Anthos on VMWare Admin Cluster?

Tags: google-anthos

During a recent admin cluster upgrade from Anthos on-prem v1.15 to v1.16 we encountered [this issue](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/latest/known-issues#duplicate-hostname-in-the-same-data-center-causes-cluster-upgrade-or-creation-failures) regarding duplicate hostnames in the same datacentre.  In an attempt to resolve this we updated the hostnames in the admin-cluster-ipblock file and force updated the cluster.  This updated the names of two of the nodes but failed to change the name of the master node.

This is the new ipblock file:

```
blocks:
- netmask: "255.255.255.192"
  gateway: "10.0.99.60"
  ips:
  - ip: "10.0.99.15"
    hostname: "admin-non-prod-1"
  - ip: "10.0.99.16"
    hostname: "admin-non-prod-2"
  - ip: "10.0.99.17"
    hostname: "admin-non-prod-3"
  - ip: "10.0.99.18"
    hostname: "admin-non-prod-4"
```

And these are our nodes following the update:

```
NAME               STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
admin-host-1       Ready    control-plane,master   3h45m   v1.27.4-gke.1600
admin-non-prod-2   Ready    <none>                 3h15m   v1.27.4-gke.1600
admin-non-prod-4   Ready    <none>                 3h10m   v1.27.4-gke.1600
```

The output of `kubectl describe cluster` shows that the Reserved Addresses has been updated as per the ipblock file:

```
        Reserved Addresses:
          Gateway:           10.0.99.60
          Hostname:          admin-non-prod-1
          Ip:                10.0.99.15
          Netmask:           26
          Gateway:           10.0.99.60
          Hostname:          admin-non-prod-2
          Ip:                10.0.99.16
          Netmask:           26
          Gateway:           10.0.99.60
          Hostname:          admin-non-prod-3
          Ip:                10.0.99.17
          Netmask:           26
          Gateway:           10.0.99.60
          Hostname:          admin-non-prod-4
          Ip:                10.0.99.18
          Netmask:           26
```

How can we update the name of the master node?